# hibernate - How to annotate a property as enum with a field

Tags: hibernate, enums, annotations

How do I map an enum with a field in it?

```
public enum MyEnum{
HIGHSCHOOL ("H"), COLLEGE("C")
private int value;
public MyEnum getInstance(String value){...}
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
@Enumerated(...)
private MyEnum eduType;
}
```

How do I annotate so that values H, C will be persisted in the database? If I keep `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, HIGHSCHOOL instead of H will be stored in the database. If I use `EnumType.ORDINAL`, 1 instead of H will be stored in the database. Kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this in Hibernate. You can write a [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) to do that for you if you want.

[This](https://www.hibernate.org/265.html) is a good start, but you'll need to replace `nullSafeSet()` and `nullSafeGet()` implementations to store your enum code (e.g. 'H' / 'C' / what have you) and return proper enum instance based on it.

If you have more than one enum type you need to do this for, you can implement [ParameterizedType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/usertype/ParameterizedType.html) interface to pass enum type as parameter or use reflection to retrieve the "code" as long as accessor methods are named consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ChssPly76 for the solution. I implemented a user type and it works well. In fact, there is an example in the hibernate community to persist the value/token in the enum. [Click here: StringValuedEnum](https://www.hibernate.org/273.html)